# Opening a Wormhole inside a Wormhole

Tags: story-identification, novel, wormhole

About twenty years ago I cut high school, and went to the mall with some friends. When I was in the book store I found a sci-fi novel, but I cannot remember the name or author at all.

All I can remember is the general gist of the book. In short, humanity has used wormholes (or a variation thereof) for interstellar-galactic travel for sometime. A descendant of this technology's inventor is met by an "entity" who informs the descendant of a problem - someone has opened a wormhole inside of a wormhole. The entity basically says space-time is in jeopardy, and because you're the descendant of the this technology's inventor, it's your mess to clean up.

Any thoughts as to who wrote this or what the novel is called?  Thanks!

Comment: Ancestor or descendant?

Comment: Descendant; sorry, its been a rough time as of late.

Comment: Do any of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormholes_in_fiction#In_written_fiction) ring a bell?